# Selenium No encuentra elemento

Tags: selenium

Tengo que automatizar las pruebas de un sistema, el login ya logre automatizarlo. Luego de loguearme ingresa a la pagina principal y es aquí donde debo seleccionar el Menu Expedientes, sin embargo pese a que coloco el id de este elemento es como si no lo ubicara.

```
WebElement menu_expediente = driver.findElement(By.id("dijit_MenuItem_3_text"));
menu_expediente.click();
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Comprueba si la página se ha cargado antes de hacer que el programa intente localizar el elemento. Básicamente puedes hacer eso de una forma provisional muy "fea" pero efectiva con un time.sleep(10), para que espere 10 segundos, justo antes de intentar recoger menu_expediente. Si esto sigue sin seleccionarlo, puedes probar a realizar el click de otra forma, haciendo un execute del elemento y el click por ejemplo, o recogiendo la url y redirigiendo directamente a la misma.

Answer (score 0):

Como dijeron en el comentario, es posible que se esté haciendo clic antes de que el elemento exista y una opción básica y sencilla para resolver es poner un `time.sleep(10)`

Otra forma puede ser con una espera explícita con [WebDriverWait](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html) y Espected_Conditions

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

# ... codigo
menu_expediente = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "dijit_MenuItem_3_text")))
menu_expediente.click();
```

Según la documentación WebDriverWait verifica cada 0.5s por la condición esperada en EC. Si transcurre el tiempo *timeout* (10s en el ejemplo) se lanza una excepción TimeOut.
Verifica también si en tu caso pudiera ser más útil `presence_of_element_located` en vez de `element_to_be_clickable` o bien otro elemento de la lista mostrada en la documentación.